# Angular - component with event attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I created component in Angular 1 which represents checkbox. I would like added event for call some action (from controller) after checked. Here is my code:

```
threeListsApp.component("checkbox",
{
    template: '<div ng-if="!checked" ng-click="check()" ng-model="checked"></div>' +
        '<div ng-if="checked" ng-click="check()" ng- model="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div>',
    controller: function checkBoxController($scope) {
        $scope.checked = false;
        $scope.check = function () {
            $scope.checked = !$scope.checked;
            if ($scope.checked) {
                //CALL SOME ACTION
            }
        }
    }
});
```

I'd like to use something like this: `<checkbox checkedEvent="{{controllerAction()}}"></checkbox>`

How to add event to component? Thanks for advices

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is my solution (I used directive):

```
threeListsApp.directive('checkbox', function ($rootScope) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        template: '<div><div ng-if="!checked" ng-click="check()" ng-model="checked"></div>' +
        '<div ng-if="checked" ng-click="check()" ng- model="checked"><i class="fa fa-check"></i></div></div>',
        replace: true,

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, model) {
            scope.checked = false;

            scope.check = function () {
                scope.checked = !scope.checked;
                if (scope.checked) {
                    var id = attrs.checked.substring(attrs.checked.lastIndexOf("(") + 1, attrs.checked.lastIndexOf(")"));
                    var method = attrs.checked.substring(0, attrs.checked.lastIndexOf("("));
                    $rootScope[method](id);
                }
            }
        }
    }; });
```

Use:

```
<checkbox checked="controllerMethod({{item.ID}})"></checkbox>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I understood the question. If you need to trigger an event on click you should simply add `$rootScope.$emit` or `$rootScope.$broadcast` to the ng-click function.

If you need to listen to an event, you could use a `$scope.$on` listener in the controller. However in this case it is preferable to use a pub-sub pattern instead of hardcode listeners in controllers.

[$rootScope documentation about events](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/rootScope.Scope)

[Angular pubSub design advices](http://eburley.github.io/2013/01/31/angularjs-watch-pub-sub-best-practices.html)

Answer (score 0):

Instead of call your controller's method, you send an event and anywhere in your code you listen this event.

In your directive:

```
$scope.$emit('myCheckboxIsChecked')
```

Anywhere in your controller:

```
$scope.$on('myCheckboxIsChecked', function(){
    // in your controller, execute your code here
});
```

If you have any problems, you can try $rootScope instead of $scope, it's less clean but it works...and check this page https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope